# System generated emails

Tags: sharepoint-email

Is there a way to change the "from" address of a system generated email?  Currently it is no-reply-sptaas.  This appears to be a default email address.  Can it be changed to something more specific related to the program office sending?  Right now this "from" address is the same for at least six separate activities in my organization.

Comment: SharePoint online or OnPrem?

Answer (score 0):

All emails sent from SharePoint will come from the same email address, you can specify the address in Central Administration under the "Outbound Email" settings.